# Can't convert WebP to JPG using libwep and Pillow

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

EDIT: it was a conflict between Anaconda and Visual Studio. I was lucky to catch it.

Libwebp shows up in my environment in the Anaconda Navigator but I still get False for

```
print (features.check_module('webp'))
```

I don't know what else could be causing it. My code works perfectly for JPG and PNG images but when I try to convert WebP into one of these I get:

```
  File "C:\Users\Ze\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2967, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000020F67040EF0>
```

I tried removing all packages and reinstalling everything but nothing :(

Here is my code:

```
def load_images_from_web(url):
    webp_format = requests.get(url)
    
    buffer = BytesIO(webp_format.content)
    
    
    image = Image.open(buffer).convert('RGB')
    
    image.save(buffer, 'jpeg')
    
    buffer.seek(0)
    
    file = {'file' : ('name', buffer.read(), 'image/jpg')}
    
    return file
```

```
 webp_format = requests.get(url)
    
    for x in range(20):
        print(BytesIO(webp_format.content).read(x))

First 20 bytes
b''
b'R'
b'RI'
b'RIF'
b'RIFF'
b'RIFF\xc6'
b'RIFF\xc67'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00W'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WE'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEB'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBP'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPV'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 '
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00'

Bytes 21-100
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89i'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa='
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3='
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfe'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1.'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1.\xd4'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1.\xd4\xbf'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1.\xd4\xbf\x98'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1.\xd4\xbf\x98\xfe'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1.\xd4\xbf\x98\xfe%'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1.\xd4\xbf\x98\xfe%\xfe'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1.\xd4\xbf\x98\xfe%\xfe\x07'
b'RIFF\xc67\x00\x00WEBPVP8 \xba7\x00\x00p\xfd\x00\x9d\x01*\xf4\x01\x93\x01>m4\x96H\xa4"\xa2*#2\n\xe9@\r\x89in\xe1s\xb6\xd9*\xfb\xff\xd2\x9f{\xf1\xff\x9b\xfa=k\xd1\xff\xe3=&x\x93\xf9o\xf1\x1f\x8c\xfe\xab\xfeE\xf5\xdf\xe7\xff/?\xc3|\xe6\xe1.\xd4\xbf\x98\xfe%\xfe\x07\xf8'
```

Comment: Your error message indicates you were trying to open a BytesIO. Can you share that code and also dump the first 20 bytes of the BytesIO in hex?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! It's supposed to be a WebP images. Shouldn't I use BytesIO in the conversion process? Here is my code https://codeshare.io/BAMBgK

Comment: Please ensure that you put your code in your question - not on some external site. You can do that by clicking `edit` under your image and pasting it in there. Then select it with the mouse and click `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic*. Also, please show the first 20 bytes of your BytesIO in hex.

Comment: Sorry about that! I edited my question with my code. I am not sure whether what I extracted is the 20 first bytes of the BytesIO in hex but I included them as well and the manner through which I got them.

Comment: I don't use anaconda or its navigator (whatever that is) but try getting PIL to tell you its build settings with `python -m PIL` or `python3 -m PIL` depending on how you start Python.

Comment: Here it is! The first command worked. It's too long to post here, though https://codeshare.io/Jbpwld

Comment: About 8-10 lines in from the start it says “WEBP not installed”. I would uninstall Pillow, re-install WEBP then reinstall Pillow once WEBP is properly installed. No idea how you would do that with conda though.

Comment: I already tried that a few times. Thank you very much, I'll try again. I am a total noob so could you recommend an alternative to Anaconda? Preferably one that will let me continue using Spyder? Is pip the other major one? I am not a programmer and when I program I usually only use C#

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again but I managed "python -m PIL" to say: "WEBP support ok, loaded 1.2.0", "WEBP Transparency support ok", "WEBP Animation support ok" and everywhere else where it said WEBP as well. However, the features.check_module command I originally posted still says false and I still get the same problem. So it seems the module is installed but PIL still has it disabled somehow. I still get the same error but it seem the byte changes. What else could I try?

Comment: One thing I see repeatedly is that people have 3+ different versions of Python installed (v2.7 and v3.5 from their OS supplier, v3.6 from **homebrew** and v3.9 that they installed from source. Then they use the **pip** from v3.6 to install **PIL** and wonder why they can't use PIL from Python v3.9.

Comment: I checked and py -0 shows only two versions, 3.9-64 and 3.8-64. I didn't install two myself, though. In fact, under Programs and Features there is only one (3.9.6 64 Bit). Do you think this could be the cause? How can I make sure? I reinstalled Python today so I think it's unlikely. I went step by step following Image.open() to see what happened and I saw the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL._webp'". It should be installed, though, since python -m PIL clearly says so.

Comment: If you do `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` you should be able to see exactly where your Python is looking for packages. If you do `import PIL` then `print(PIL.__path__)` you should be able to see which PIL you are using. You must be able to somehow check those against your conda settings. Sorry, I can't help that well as I neither use Windows nor conda.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have helped me a lot already. I'll try this and see if I can figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: You, my good sir, are a genius. Here's a cake. THANK YOU SO F******* MUCH!!!!!! It was actually a conflict between Visual Studio and Anaconda. I uninstalled everything then install Conda and it works like a charm. I love you forever and you are a gentleman and a scholar. Good day and tatata!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a conflict between Visual Studio and Anaconda. Uninstalled everything then reinstalled Anaconda. Hooray! Thanks Mark Setchell for leading me to the answer